# Error installing cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux.run in WSL2

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda

This is my version of Ubuntu：

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --list --verbose
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
```

This is my gcc version：

```
zhao@ZhaoYH:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This is the result after entering `nvidia-smi`：

```
zhao@DESKTOP-CBA46OT:~$ nvidia-smi
Sat Sep 16 08:57:03 2023
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.50                 Driver Version: 531.79       CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 L...    On | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   34C    P8                1W /  N/A|     10MiB /  8188MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        23      G   /Xwayland                                 N/A      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I followed [Nvidia's tutorial for CUDA installation](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=runfile_local), an error occurred when I reached the second line of the command:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.2/local_installers/cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux.run
```

```
zhao@DESKTOP-CBA46OT:~$ sudo sh cuda_12.2.2_535.104.05_linux.run
[sudo] password for zhao:
sh: 1: dkms: not found
 Installation failed. See log at /var/log/cuda-installer.log for details.
zhao@DESKTOP-CBA46OT:~$ cat /var/log/cuda-installer.log
[INFO]: Driver not installed.
[INFO]: Checking compiler version...
[INFO]: gcc location: /usr/bin/gcc

[INFO]: gcc version: gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

[INFO]: Initializing menu
[INFO]: Disabling driver option for WSL install
[INFO]: nvidia-fs.setKOVersion(2.17.5)
[INFO]: Setup complete
[INFO]: Installing: CUDA Demo Suite 12.2
[WARNING]: Unable to create .pc files, permission denied at /usr/lib/pkgconfig/!
[WARNING]: Cannot find manpages to install.
[INFO]: Installing: CUDA Documentation 12.2
[WARNING]: Unable to create .pc files, permission denied at /usr/lib/pkgconfig/!
[WARNING]: Cannot find manpages to install.
[INFO]: Installing: Kernel Objects
[INFO]: cudaItem::install - kernelobjects
[INFO]: Able to write to /usr/local/kernelobjects/
[INFO]: Installing: nvidia-fs
[INFO]: cudaItem::install - kernelobjects
[INFO]: dkms not found
[INFO]: DKMS is not installed,skip to static kernel module install
[INFO]: previous version of nvidia-fs is not installed, nvidia-fs version: 2.17.5 will be installed.
[INFO]: getting mofed Status
[INFO]: installation status shows that mofed is not installed,please install mofed before continuing nvidia_fs install.
[ERROR]: Install of nvidia-fs failed, quitting
```

My first installation was successful, but then the `~/.bashrc` file was damaged. So I reinstalled Ubuntu. I tried various methods on the Internet to completely clear the remaining CUDA and Nvidia files, but I still got the same error. I even reinstalled Windows 11, but the error still did not disappear. I went to the official Nvidia forum for help, but no one answered.

### One important piece of information is that I followed other methods and tried to view `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` but the file does not exist at all and `/var/log/nvidia/` is an empty folder

Answer (score 1):

> When I followed [Nvidia's tutorial for CUDA installation](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=runfile_local)

That looks to be your main problem.  You installed the CUDA Toolkit for Ubuntu, when you should have installed the one specifically for [WSL-Ubuntu](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0) (the next one in the list).

The normal CUDA Toolkit includes the *Ubuntu* driver for the GPU, which is *not* what you need.  See this important statement from the [actual tutorial](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html):

> Once a Windows NVIDIA GPU driver is installed on the system, CUDA becomes available within WSL 2. The CUDA driver installed on Windows host will be stubbed inside the WSL 2 as `libcuda.so`, therefore **users must not install any NVIDIA GPU Linux driver within WSL 2**. One has to be very careful here as the default CUDA Toolkit comes packaged with a driver, and it is easy to overwrite the WSL 2 NVIDIA driver with the default installation.

Since you've done exactly that, your best best is going to be to wipe Ubuntu under WSL2 and reinstall.  As far as I'm aware, Nvidia has not supplied any instructions for recovering from that "bad state" after installing the wrong CUDA Toolkit.

Since it sounds like you have just reinstalled, I'm going to **assume** that you don't have any files to back up, but if you do, please make sure you have done so, since the following will **erase all data and configuration** from Ubuntu in WSL2.  There is **no confirmation or recovery**.

From PowerShell:

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04
ubuntu2204.exe
```

The last line will re-run the installer that asks for you to set a username and password.  After doing so, proceed as usual:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Then follow the [instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html) carefully ;-).

Note that there are three package options on the download page.  Using the `.deb` versions is typically "safest", but given the native code we're already installing from Nvidia, I think we can trust the runfile (`.run`) version.

The one downside (that I'm aware of) in the `.deb` is that as of a few weeks ago when I last installed using that method, it still did not add `nvcc` to the path properly.  You can do that manually, but the `.run` does correctly set the necessary environment variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Since there are too many terms, I will repeat my understanding to you and please see if it is correct.
First I uninstalled Ubuntu and reinstalled it so I needed to reopen my Ubuntu account, then I downloaded the .run file for the wsl-Ubuntu version and followed the instructions to install it. (One problem here is that the Ubuntu in my WSL2 is version 20.04, but there is only 1or 2 in wsl-Ubuntu, not 20.04. Is this a match?) Thank you

Comment: Can I delete the Nvidia driver under Windows so that I can install the .run file under Ubuntu?

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang No!  You *need* the Windows Nvidia driver - That's the *only* one that works with Ubuntu/WSL2.  The Ubuntu Nvidia driver will not work, since WSL2 can't communicate directly with the GPU/hardware layer.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask if there is no version 20.04 for WSL-Ubuntu. Should I choose 2?

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang Yes, that is "Version 2 of the CUDA Toolkit", not referring to an Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are the only one who helped me after I faced the problem

Comment: Hello, I just tried your method and downloaded the .run file under WSL-Ubuntu, but the same error occurred during installation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. When installing CUDA, the cross was selected instead of canceled, so I kept canceling the CUDA toolkit, which resulted in many errors.

Comment: Great to hear you figured it out!  Also thank you for replacing the images with text.  Now, if anyone else has that error, they'll now be able to search for it and find your answer.